# Retrieve pages from block ContentReference

Tags: content-management-system, block, episerver-7

Is it possible to retrieve pages that uses a shared block instance in EPIserver 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ContentSoftLinkRepository` to get references to/from the content item. Let's say `blockLink` is the content reference of your block.

```cs
// resolving the repository. It can also be injected as a property or in your constructor.
var linkRepository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ContentSoftLinkRepository>();

// loading soft links for your block
var referencingContentLinks = linkRepository.Load(blockLink, true).Where(link =>
                    link.SoftLinkType == ReferenceType.PageLinkReference &&
                    !ContentReference.IsNullOrEmpty(link.OwnerContentLink))
                .Select(link => link.OwnerContentLink)
                .ToList();
```

Now you have the list of content links of pages/blocks/... that uses/references your block.

Comment: How would that work for blocks? I.e. if I need a list of blocks referencing a given block. There is no `BlockLinkReference` or similar in `ReferenceType` enum...